# Does Improved Channel increase DC for Command Undead?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

The Command Undead-feat uses one channel and has the same save-DC as the channel. The Improved-Channel-feat increases the DC for the channel. Does this include the DC of the Command Undead?

For reference:

- [Improved Channel](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/feats.html#improved-channel)
- [Command Undead](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/feats.html#command-undead)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it does affect Turn Undead and Command Undead DCs.  Though unclear in the RAW, [this was clarified by James Jacobs on the Paizo forums](http://paizo.com/forums/dmtz2u4o&page=397?Ask-James-Jacobs-ALL-your-Questions-Here#19802).

Comment: Thanks. I think James Jacobs has a bit authority regarding Pathfinder-rules, so I accept your answer instead of starweds.

Answer (score 3):

By the RAW, no.  This is because the [Command Undead](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/feats.html#command-undead) feat does not say to use the Channel Energy DC; it just happens to have the same formula.  And it consumes a use of your channeling ability, but doesn't itself count as the same ability.

I think it would be a reasonable house rule to have Improved Channel affect related abilities, though.